# Make checkboxes not required to enable button if hidden

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have 4 checkboxes on a page and a button that is not enabled until the checkboxes are checked. I am running into a problem when some of the checkboxes are hidden. When they are hidden I can't check them and then the button will never be enabled because all of the boxes are not checked. What I want to do is make the checkboxes not required to enable the button if they are hidden. The way I have it pictured in my head would be a long series of if/else statements and would just be ugly and complicated. I know there has to be an easier solution I just can't seem to wrap my head around what it would be. I will provide the code for the checkboxes and button and then describe what I was thinking would work so you can get an idea of why I think there is probably an easier way. Also, we are using Angular in this web app. Not sure if that makes a difference in the solution or not but I figured I would mention it.

The code for the checkboxes is:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="bes-confirmation" ng-model="checkboxes.besConfirmation" ng-show="migrationState.migrationData.usersWithBESEnabled.length > 0" />
    <label for="bes-confirmation" ng-show="migrationState.migrationData.usersWithBESEnabled.length > 0" >I understand -- BES</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="public-folder-confirmation" ng-model="checkboxes.publicFolderConfirmation" ng-show="migrationState.migrationData.publicFoldersEnabled"/>
    <label for="public-folder-confirmation" ng-show="migrationState.migrationData.publicFoldersEnabled" >I understand -- PF</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="adr-confirmation" ng-model="checkboxes.adrConfirmation" ng-show="!migrationState.migrationData.adrRecordIsCorrect" />
    <label for="adr-confirmation" ng-show="!migrationState.migrationData.adrRecordIsCorrect" >I understand -- ADR</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="sdr-confirmation" ng-model="checkboxes.sdrConfirmation" ng-show="migrationState.migrationData.splitDomainRoutingEnabled"/>
    <label for="sdr-confirmation" ng-show="migrationState.migrationData.splitDomainRoutingEnabled">I understand -- SDR</label>
</div>
```

The button is:

```
<button type="button" 
            ng-click="scheduleMigration()"
            ng-disabled="!allCheckboxesAreChecked()">               
            Schedule Migration!
</button>
```

The allCheckBoxesAreChecked function is:

```
$scope.allCheckboxesAreChecked = function() {
    return $scope.checkboxes.besConfirmation && $scope.checkboxes.adrConfirmation && $scope.checkboxes.sdrConfirmation && $scope.checkboxes.publicFolderConfirmation;
}
```

I figured i could have a series of if/else statements that would just be something like (going to write in pseudocode for simplicity)

```
if !publicFoldersEnabled
  return besConfirmation && sdrConfirmation && adrConfirmation
else if !splitDomainRoutingEnabled
  return sdrConfirmation && adrConfirmation && publicFolderConfirmation
```

etc...

I could continue with every possible combo of visible and hidden checkboxes but I feel like there has to be a better way to do this. Any ideas on how I could do this easier/cleaner and with a lot less code than a series of if/else statements? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to normalize all your checkboxes' behaviours. Make it so all all checkboxes look like :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.someUniqueName" ng-show=migrationState.migrationData.someUniqueName"/>
```

You could then reference all checkboxes you wish to monitor in some array :

```
var requirements = ['someUniqueName1', 'someUniqueName2', ... ];
```

Finally, just rewrite your validation function to loop over it :

```
$scope.validateCheckboxes = function() {
    var okay = true ;
    angular.forEach(requirements, function(req, index) {
        okay = okay && ($scope.checkboxes[req] || !$scope.migrationState.migrationData[req]);
    return okay;
};
```

If you really wish to keep checkbox specific behaviours (like the one checkbox whose ng-show check is a !migrationState...), you can have requirements that are full-fledged objects instead of simple strings, whose variables could be used as flags to choose the correct test e.g.

```
var requirements = [{'name':'someUniqueName1', 'reverse':false, 'checkLength':true}, ...]
```

This kind of setup has the added advantage of being easily extensible : just add a string to your requirements array if you ever add another checkbox and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is going to do the trick. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Put your checkboxes inside a form and use ng-required attribute, and then enable the button only if the form is valid:

```
    <form name="form" ng-submit="scheduleMigration()">
      <div ng-show="migrationState.migrationData.usersWithBESEnabled.length &gt; 0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="bes-confirmation" ng-model="checkboxes.besConfirmation" ng-required="migrationState.migrationData.usersWithBESEnabled.length &gt; 0" />
        <label for="bes-confirmation">I understand -- BES</label>
      </div> 
      ...
      <!-- other checkboxes -->
      ...
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!form.$valid">Schedule Migration!</button>
    </form>
```

You can make it even shorter if you use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` -- in that case the element is not in the DOM tree at all, so you can replace `ng-required="..."` with just `required`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I can see how this would work. Going to go with Sycomor's solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the checkbox's show logic elsewhere so that you have, perhaps something like this:

```
scope.visibleCheckboxes.besConfirmation = migrationState.migrationData.usersWithBESEnabled.length > 0
scope.visibleCheckboxes.publicFolderConfirmation = migrationState.migrationData.publicFoldersEnabled
scope.visibleCheckboxes.adrConfirmation = !migrationState.migrationData.adrRecordIsCorrect
scope.visibleCheckboxes.sdrConfirmation = migrationState.migrationData.splitDomainRoutingEnabled
```

Then use those scope variables in your ng-show.  Then you can do this:

```
function allCheckboxesAreChecked() {
    var vC = scope.visibleCheckboxes
    for ( checkbox in vC ) {
        if ( vC.hasOwnProperty(checkbox) && vc[checkbox] && !scope.checkboxes[checkbox] ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```